# Prove $\sin^4\theta+\cos^4 \theta= 1-2\sin^2 \theta cos^2 \theta $

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to prove:

$$\sin^4\theta+\cos^4 \theta= 1-2\sin^2 \theta cos^2 \theta ?$$

Comment: I think there's a typo in formula: the left-hand  side should be $\sin^4X\color{red}+\cos^4X$.\,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sin^4\theta+\cos^4\theta=(\sin^4\theta\color{red}{+2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}+\cos^4\theta) \color{red}{- 2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}$$
$$=(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)^2\color{red}{-2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}$$
$$=1-2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta$$

Comment: can you explain from where minus comes from in RHS  i think there should be plus.

Comment: @kamaljitsingh I have edited my answer.

Comment: thank u very much for your time. now i understand :)

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\sin^4\theta+\cos^4\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta
&\Longleftrightarrow \sin^4\theta+\cos^4\theta+2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta=1\\
\end{align*}

which is always true since
$$
\sin^4\theta+\cos^4\theta+2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta=(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)^2=1^2=1
$$
so the identity is proved.

Answer (score 1):

Another direct way would be to use $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2 \theta=1$ also in the forms $\sin^2 \theta = 1-\cos^2 \theta$ and $\cos^2 \theta = 1-\sin^2 \theta$ as follows:

$$\sin^4 \theta + \cos^4 \theta = \sin^2 \theta (1-\cos^2\theta)+\cos^2 \theta(1-\sin^2\theta)=1-2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta$$